# How to prepare salsify (schwarzwurzeln) to minimise sap?

Tags: vegetables, peeling

This morning I tried cooking [salsify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsify) (aka [Schwarzwurzeln](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorzonera_hispanica)) for the first time.

It needs to be peeled before cooking, which I did rapidly and with a bowl of water nearby, as per advice on various internet sites.  However, it still left an unpleasant, sticky, orange sap over my hands and the utensils.  It lasts for a long time and is very difficult to remove.

What is the best way to prepare salsify to minimise the amount of sap??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rinse the salsify first before using, that will help.
Use a sharp peeler. Ive found that dull peelers create a lot more sap.

as soon as you have peeled it, drop the salsify into acidulated water ( water + lemon juice).  The acids help prevent the color change that occurs.

Also wipe up the area with a damp cloth as you work.  This will keep things clean and prevent your hands and everything you touch getting tacky.

Answer (score 2):

This is how my parents do it:

1. For Peeling they cover the desk with old newspaper.
2. Then they put on single-use gloves and peel the salsify
3. After peeling they grab
   them and wash them outside on the lawn with the garden hose.

The newspaper and gloves can be thrown away and the only thing left for cleaning is the peeler and the pot you have cooked the salsify in. I think, you can put them into the dish washer.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me a few times: Rinse, then just work with hands and vegetable completely underwater in a big casserole dish or mixing bowl for peeling and cutting to size... hold pieces with tongs to rinse afterwards...